# namespace altering the function definition

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a small snipped of code, which just produces a function to get the current directory for either Windows or Linux platform:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
#include <string>
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir getcwd
 #endif


    std::string getcwd(){
    char mCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    GetCurrentDir(mCurrentPath, sizeof(mCurrentPath));
    return *(new std::string (mCurrentPath));

    }
```

This is all great and working; however, I'd like to make the `getcwd()` function inside the namespace, `fUtils`, hence I did this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
#include <string>
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir getcwd
 #endif

namespace fUtils{
    std::string getcwd(){
    char mCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    GetCurrentDir(mCurrentPath, sizeof(mCurrentPath));
    return *(new std::string (mCurrentPath));

    }
}
```

But this gives an error in `VSCode` which says:

> `no matching function for call to 'getcwd'`

What mistake am I making in this? If this isn't how I put the function to the namespace `fUtils`, then how should I put it into the namespace?

Comment: `return *(new std::string)` is an excellent way to leak memory. You are allocating a pointer that you immediately lose the address of, then copy anyway, and never delete and therefore leak.

Comment: What line of code causes `no matching function for call to 'getcwd'`?  In your actual code, do you call `getcwd` or `fUtiils::getcwd`?  Also, if you can uses C++17 you can use [`current_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) instead

Comment: `return *(new std::string (mCurrentPath));` -- This can simply be `return mCurrentPath;`.  This gets rid of the memory.

Comment: @CoryKramer , thanks for the super helpful tip

Comment: @NathanOliver , wow, I didn't know that

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , you're right, didn't notice that, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `fUtils::getcwd()` function is attempting to call *itself* when the `GetCurrentDir` macro is evaluated (to `getcwd`), and this results in a function that expects no argument but is being given two arguments.

To resolve this, add the global namespace operator (`::`) in the definitions for `GetCurrentDir`, as follows:

```cpp
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir ::_getcwd
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir ::getcwd
#endif
```

Then, in your function body, it is clear to the compiler that your aren't looking for a 'recursive' (and invalid) call.

Answer (score 2):

Use of macros in such context is invitation to problems in future.

Just wrap those functions with own API and all problems will be resolved.

Header file:

```cpp
#include <string>

namepsace fUtils {
std::string getcwd();
}
```

Then you can have platform specific cpp files, Windows:

```cpp
namepsace fUtils {
std::string getcwd() {
    char mCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
    ::_getcwd(mCurrentPath, sizeof(mCurrentPath));
    return {mCurrentPath};
}
}
```

Mac version is obvious.

You also can use this macros inside single cpp file and this way contain them there if you do not what to do larger clean up.

### Side notes:

- there is `boost::filesystem` which has such api also use of `boost::filesystem::path` is quite handy
- C++17 introduces `std::filesystem`, but it is not well supported yet (for example MacOS)
- if you wrap this functionality in classes you will open your way for better testing (mocks).